# "Authentication Required" error message when running "npx expo prebuild" in Terminal

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm definitely logged into my expo account because when I run expo login, I'm told that I'm logged in.

So I created a new React Native project and I'm trying to run `npx expo prebuild` command in terminal, inside of my project directory, but all I'm seeing is the following...

[image]

How can I get it to build the projects as per the npx expo prebuild command?

Much appreciated!